# Issue with Jmeter SSHMON sample collector ( received data is not parsed by the plugin)

Tags: jmeter

I’m doing a performance test using Jmeter and during the test I’m collecting the statistics for backend server performance , for this purpose I use SSHMON sample collector listener  in my test plan
https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon

I have also configured a CSV file path to check the response data received from the server
Issue is that

- Data is not recorded in the CSV file and also there is no graph shown for SSHMON listener
- In the jemeter logs I can see the following error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: " [2J"
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:434) ~[?:?]
    at nz.co.breakpoint.jmeter.vizualizers.sshmon.SSHMonSampler.generateSamples(SSHMonSampler.java:86) [jmeter-sshmon-1.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.MonitoringResultsCollector.processConnectors(MonitoringResultsCollector.java:215) [jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.6.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.MonitoringResultsCollector.run(MonitoringResultsCollector.java:122) [jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.6.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
```

To verify the SSH configuration  and the received data format , I tried to make a SSH connection to the backend server using putty and with same user/pwd and command , I get the data in Putty  , please see the attached screenshot

Do I have to change the powershell script to change the format of CPU data, if yes then in which format?
I did not get any info on plugin page.

I would really appreciate if you could provide me some help for this case.

[image: SSHMON config and Putty request results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue appears to be related to the terminal control sequence sent
as output of the remote Powershell server application back to the local client,
i.e. the JMeter plugin vs. the Powershell command line.

The characters `[2J` would be the "Erase in Display" sequence (refer ANSI Escape Codes, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences).

In one case those characters would presumably be interpreted by the terminal application displaying the output (e.g. Putty or Cmd window) and the output looks correct.

In the other case however, the control sequence characters are received by the plugin and rejected as unparsable number.

A very similar issue has been [reported](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins/c/5g2JqivexXE/m/g3Noba2YCAAJ) on the JMeter-Plugins Google Group.

The version 1.3 of the SSHMon plugin uses a different SSH client library which seems to fix the issue according to feedback on the Google Groups thread.

Recommended solution: Upgrade to version 1.3 or later.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the JMeter SSHMon plugin.

Comment: @tillin, thanks a lot , it seems this issue was caused because somehow in my ..lib\ext both 1.2 and 1.3 versions were kept ( not sure how this happened) but after removing 1.2 version , it started working. Thanks a lot for your help